# start and kill rosbag record from bash shell script

Tags: ros, rosbag, shell, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say we want to record a rosbag, and run a python script from a bash script.

```
rosbag record -o /file/name /topic
PID=$!
sleep 2
python ./run_ROS_script.py
kill -INT $PID
```

so if you leave out -INT it kills the rosbag, but not nicely: it leaves the rosbag in .active status. If you add -INT (same thing as running ctrl+c on the rosbag process) then the rosbag never finishes, and doesn't leave .active status.

So ... what gives? Why can't we nicely kill this rosbag record?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275441/start-and-kill-rosbag-record-from-bash-shell-script/) by [buckley.toby](https://answers.ros.org/users/30452/buckley.toby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2017-11-09

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could run your rosbag with a Not anonymous node name

```
rosbag record -o /file/name /topic __name:=my_bag
```

and then kill it via rosnode kill :

```
rosnode kill /my_bag
```

This assures that rosbag stops gracefully.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Girmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29032/girmi/) on 2018-02-16**:
The correct command that worked for me (ROS Kinetic) is:

```
rosbag record -o /file/name /topic __name:=my_bag
rosnode kill /my_bag
```

Note the double underscore before the name param (see the "Special keys" section at [Remapping Arguments](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping Arguments))

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-16**:
You're correct. I've just edited the answer by @Wolf.

**Comment by [stegelid](https://answers.ros.org/users/45022/stegelid/) on 2019-08-21**:
You can set a trap in your bash script, catching SIGINT and call rosnode kill from there, eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "rosnode kill /bagger" SIGINT
rosbag record /my_topic __name:=bagger &
roslaunch mypackage launch.launch
```

**Comment by [mch](https://answers.ros.org/users/31598/mch/) on 2021-10-28**:\

> rosnode kill /my_bag
> This assures that rosbag stops gracefully.

That does not seem to stop gracefully though. Rosbag name is *.bag.active not just *.bag